# DataSourceInitializer : ApplicationEventMulticaster is not initialized

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.0 with embedded h2database.
The database is initialized using schema.sql file in the classpath.
It worked fine until I added @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation to the WebSecurityConfiguration class.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized** exception is thrown from DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts

What may be the problem ?

Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like [#1711](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1711). `WebSecurityConfiguration` is in a different class of your main `Application`, right?

Comment: `WebSecurityConfiguration` is in a different class. I also tried to make it inner class of main Application. But I am getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to not use the `init` method to setup JDBC authentication. Try with a separate class that extends `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` and override the `config` method.

Comment: I moved JDBC authentication setup to the `configure` method but I am getting the same exception.

Comment: The issue looks same as [1386](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1386). So I moved DML into schema.sql.